# Problem with files using prolog (Existence error)

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

Why would the file run with no problems when using Eclipse but when I create a jar file of the same program I can't run it locally on my pc?

This is the error I get where a is an input and signal.pl is a file I pass located in Desktop:

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop>java -jar ADE2.jar a signal.pl
Exception in thread "main" org.jpl7.PrologException: PrologException: error(existence_error(source_sink, a), _0)
        at org.jpl7.Query.fetchNextSolution(Query.java:438)
        at org.jpl7.Query.hasMoreSolutions(Query.java:342)
        at org.jpl7.Query.oneSolution(Query.java:872)
        at org.jpl7.Query.hasSolution(Query.java:950)
        at ADE.executeGorgias(ADE.java:19)
        at ADE.main(ADE.java:41)
```

Comment: Well, it's opening file `a` and not finding it (which is kinda an "existence error" à la ISO: "An object on which an operation is to be performed does not exist."). Print the [absolute_file_name/3](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=absolute_file_name/3) before opening the file to check what Prolog thinks the location of file `a` is.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have two different working directories in your two scenaries.

SWI-Prolog provides the [`working_directory/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=working_directory/2) predicate in the form of `working_directory(-Old, +New)`.

As the documentation states:

> Unify `Old` with an absolute path to the current working directory and change working directory to `New`. Use the pattern `working_directory(CWD, CWD)` to get the current directory.

Thus, I would suggest to test `working_directory(CWD, CWD)` in both cases to see if your working directory differs, which may lead to probelms when working with relative paths.

Edit: You can also use [`absolute_file_name/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=absolute_file_name/3) to ensure that your "Eclipse use case" and your "jar use case" resolve the file in the same way.

Comment: I tried changing the working directory but that didn't change anything. Still the same problem

Comment: @MariosGeorgiou Did you also try the hint by @David Tonhofer to use `absolute_file_name/3`? What does it print in the "Eclipse" case, what in the "jar" case?